# Ubuntu 14.04: add physical space drive to folder with existing content

Tags: filesystems, hard-drive, mount, ubuntu-14.04

system: a VPS running Ubuntu 14.04, apache 2.4.7

I added a virtual disk drive to my VPS server. I would like that the OS (Ubuntu 14.04) resides on its own "system" drive, and my clients files reside on another "data" drive.

But their location: `/data/www` is currently on the "system" drive.

Whilst not being very familiar with the linux way of handling drive space, I figured I could mount the new `/dev/sdc` drive into `/data` ( `mount /dev/sdc /data`) but then all the existing content in /data disappeared. Fortunately, umounting made the files available once again. 
So my question is: how can I use the available space on `/dev/sdc` to add it to the `/data` folder (which, I suppose, is on `/dev/sda`) ?

In case it helps, here is the output of `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda        4.9G  3.0G  1.7G  64% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
devtmpfs       1004M   12K 1004M   1% /dev
none             38M  264K   38M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            189M     0  189M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
tmpfs            24K     0   24K   0% /var/gadin
/dev/sdc        4.8G   11M  4.6G   1% /srv/data01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to do it this way

0./ Stop services Apache, php-fdm and mysql

1./ Move data directory to /dev/sdc

```
mv /data /srv/data01
```

2./ Create the /data directory

```
mkdir /data
```

3./ Mount /srv/data01/data as a directory (and not a device) by using `--bind`

```
mount /srv/data01/data /data --bind
```

Answer (score 1):

Mount the drive somewhere else (you already did this), move the data to it, then remount the drive at its intended location.

Comment: Could you walk me through the list of commands?

Comment: But you appear to already know the commands (except, apparently, for `mv`)!

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on mount. I tried once and seeing all my files disappear made me nervous... lame, i know. It's the " remount the drive at its intended location" part that seemed to not work for me.

Comment: Right, _after_ you move the files to the new disk!

Comment: so `mount /dev/sdc /data` will do it?

Comment: argl I think i made a mistake. I did `mount /dev/sdc / ` and now, a lot of noisy characters appear when I ls ...